# Oracle Column Not Allowed Here Default Value

Tags: oracle, sequence, default-value

The problem is about the DEFAULT value using a sequence on line 4.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE SEQUENCE CHANNEL_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;

    CREATE TABLE "CHANNEL" (  
    "ID_CHANNEL" NUMBER(18,0) DEFAULT CHANNEL_SEQ.NEXTVAL,  
    "IS_ACTIVE" VARCHAR2(1 CHAR) NOT NULL,  
    "BATCH_SIZE" NUMBER(3,0) NOT NULL,
    "MAX_DOCS_IN_PROCESS" NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL,
    "RECEIVER_ID" NUMBER(18,0) NOT NULL,
    "LAST_POS_SESSION_TIME" DATE,
     CONSTRAINT "PK_CHANNEL" PRIMARY KEY ("ID_CHANNEL"),
     CONSTRAINT "FK_RECEIVER_ID_CHANNEL" FOREIGN KEY ("RECEIVER_ID") REFERENCES   "MSG_OUT"("MSG_OUT_ID"),
     CONSTRAINT "CHK_IS_ACTIVE" CHECK (IS_ACTIVE IN ('Y', 'N'))
   );
```

The error messages are :

> "SQL Error: ORA-00984: column not allowed here"

All help and hints are welcome.

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: @LalitKumarB I disagree that this question is duplicate. This question about column syntax and problem mostly related to the fact that different version of oracle allow or not allow this syntax. That should be the answer here. Now, how to do it - explained in the one answer here and the linked question. So, one question is **how** and another is **why**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `seq.NEXTVAL` as default value.

For this purpose (auto-filling) you should create trigger, like

```
CREATE OT REPLACE TRIGGER 
BEFORE INSERT 
ON CHANNEL
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
:NEW.ID_CHANNEL:=CHANNEL_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
END;
```

Comment: @your answer relates only to certain versions of Oracle

Comment: Only before Oracle 12g. They've added support for this later.